# HTML select tag has Onchange function which calls a java-script, is getting called even when it is not called explicitly

Tags: javascript, html, visualforce

I am using the select tag in VF page for a picklist.

```
select class="selectData" disabled="true" onchange = "fetchData(this);" id="selectDataId1"
```

The fetchData(this) calls a JS function.This Onchange function is sometimes randomly getting called even when there is no explicit changes to the dropdown. 
There are some other text fields on the page. It has been noticed that this issue is occurring only from certain laptops and when these text field values are selected from the cache. As soon as the value from the cache is selected for the text field, it calls the fetchData(this) of the dropdown. 
Why text field changes(picked up from cache) are causing the dropdown Onchange getting called? and how do I fix this?
[cached options for a text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0V1U.png)

Comment: The onchange callback occurs every time the selected item in the select list changes.  This is the default behavior.

Comment: The onchange of dropdown is getting called on the text field. See the attached image.

Comment: I'm going off your code, which shows a onchange on a select tag.